# With fullcalendar, how to do date selection alone first, and once the dates are selected, send the dates with a submit button?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

In the calendar I have a week-view with 1 hour time slots, and I want to be able to select any time slot for that week. Once all time slots are selected/unselected, I want to send the selected time slots with a submit button.

On the design I have, on the calendar, for each time slot there is a checkbox. But it is okay, if the selected state for the time slot is just a different background color instead of a checkbox.

I have been searching the docs, but I do not see examples like this. It would help a lot if at least I knew this can be done with Fullcalendar.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you asking how to enable multiple selections in fullCalendar? You can use the `select` callback, which allows multiple _consecutive_ timeslots to be selected all at once. If you want to allow selection of non-consecutive slots, you can combine that callback with your own custom code to keep track of all the selected areas in an array, and then provide the user with a button to submit that once they have completed their selections. If necessary, add/remove "background" events to fullcalendar during this process so they can see what they've selected